# SQL server-declare local variable: "there is already an object named '' in the database"

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, variables, local

I wrote the following stored procedure, in which I use a local variable 'syncParam':

```
declare @syncParam bit

select isSync into syncParam from MyTable where id=@id
if (@syncParam='True')...
else ...  

return @syncParam
```

When I executed this stored procedure at the first time it worked, but after that I get the following error: "there is already an object named 'syncParam' in the database".

What did I miss?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want

```
select @syncParam  = isSync from MyTable where id=@id
```

`SELECT INTO` will insert records into a new table.  Go look, you should have a `syncParam` table now.

Answer (score 3):

you might consider using a temp table .. just rename the table #syncParam